# Why would my XAML editor be giving me an error but the project compiles and runs fine?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've implemented the [Attached Behavior Command pattern](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) which **compiles and runs fine**, but strangely my XAML editor is giving the error:

> The attachable property 'Behaviors'
>   was not found in type
>   'CommandBehaviorCollection'.

in this XAML:

```
   <c:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors>
        <c:BehaviorBinding Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" 
                           Command="{Binding PressedLeftButton}"
                           CommandParameter="MainBorder123"/>
        <c:BehaviorBinding Event="MouseRightButtonDown" 
                           Command="{Binding PressedRightButton}"
                           CommandParameter="MainBorder123"/>
    </c:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors>
```

However, I can compile and run it fine.

I've rebuilt the project, the solution, closed and opened it, but the XAML editor still gives me this error.

Has anyone experienced an **incongruity between XAML editor and compiler** like this before? Any idea how to make the XAML editor see that there really isn't a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I normally turn the XAML Editor off and use the XML Editor instead. It's faster and doesn't throw these red herring "errors" at you. I haven't had a chance to try it yet, but hopefully VS2010 does a much better job in this area.

Comment: How do you "turn it off", I don't see it under tools | options | text editors | xaml for instance.

Comment: You need to map the .xaml extension to the XML editor. It's in the options somewhere under File Extensions.